# Change the css of an input type image depending on label text

Tags: php, html, css

As the title says, I want to change the input source depending on the label text for example when I have label text = `"*.pdf"` I want to change the input src image to PDFIcon.png.

How I say to the css that

if `label.txt="*.pdf"` do `input.src="PDFIcon.png"`

if `label.txt="*.jpg"` do `input.src="JPGIcon.png"`

if `label.txt="*.docx"` do `input.src="DOCXIcon.png"` ...

Edit: Problem solved

I don't know the down vote cause,I am newbie in web application ,I did my research but I find nothing, any way here is my try just in case, hope it be useful:

(php code)

```
$extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            switch ($extension) {
                case 'pdf':
                    echo '<li class="file"><label id="labelFile"><input id="fileIcon" type="image" src="./theme/pdf_icon_16.png" />' . $file . '</label></li>';


...

                default:
                    echo '<li class="file"><label id="labelFile"><input id="fileIcon" type="image" src="./theme/defaultfileIcon.jpg" />' . $file . '</label></li>';
```

Comment: you can't do it with css, you need to use javascript.

Comment: you just made a condition and called an element attribute.. javascript right there

Comment: wait a minute.. look at your code that changes the label.txt and put the input.src there too.

Comment: actually I am parsing a tree and I want to charge the input.src with the appropriate image depending on file extension , I hope it's clearer now

Comment: What do you mean by "input source"? Can you show HTML of what you want?

Comment: my input here has an image type

Answer (score 1):

First : give an id or a class to your label then you can get the value like this:

```
var labelValue = $("#myId").val();
```

Try to use the split function (if your image name doesnt contain a .) you can do

`var extension = labelValue.split(".")[1]`

Then you can use a switch to choose your src

`switch(extension){
case 'PDF':
$("#imageId").attr("src", "PDFIcon.png");
break;
case...
default:
...
}`

Hope it helps! 
Sorry for my english